# FIFO queue via memcache backend

Tags: memcached, fifo

Is it plausible to implement a FIFO queue with memcached?

I found a recipe for [redis](http://www.rediscookbook.org/implement_a_fifo_queue.html)

As far as I know memcached has not list type. The [`append()`](https://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewCommands#append) method of memcached looks very basic.

Is it plausible to implement a FIFO with memcached?

Comment: nothing is impossible but why bother? Redis beats memcached in so many different aspects and as you have already discovered having a queue is one of them

Comment: @e4c5 if "no" is the answer to "Is it plausible to implement a FIFO queue with memcached?". Then please write an answer. I will accept it, up-vote it and give you the bounty. BTW, I changed "possible" to "plausible". Is "plausible" the right word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it plausible to implement a FIFO queue with memcached? **Yes**. Is it practical **no**. The following is a very basic implementation with python.

```
from pylibmc import Client


class Queue: 
    """A sample implementation of a First-In-First-Out
       data structure."""
    def __init__(self):
        self.in_ptr = 0
        self.out_ptr = 0
        self.client = Client(['/tmp/memcached.sock'])

    def push(self, obj):
        key = 'fifoq{0}'.format(self.in_ptr)
        self.client.add(key, obj)
        self.in_ptr += 1


    def pop(self):
        if self.in_ptr > self.out_ptr:
            key = 'fifoq{0}'.format(self.out_ptr)
            ret = self.client.get(key)
            self.out_ptr += 1

            return ret

        return None
```

This has no thread safety, does not do type checking and does not catch any exceptions. Once you add those features it will work reasonably well as a FIFO queue but I am not convinced that using memcached is the ideal solution. As you have discovered yourself redis already has this feature and it will be much more robust and scalable.

Comment: I am not out to prove that this is practical. As I have commented to the question, my recommendation is to use redis. This is just a proof of concept answer to the question whether it's plausible. I didn't set out to write a full featured library here.

Comment: Also leaking is not a problem, memcache clears out expired keys on it's own. You should be more concerned out keys that are in the part of the queue that interests us getting expired and being purged.

Answer (score 1):

No, because you can never be sure that a chunk of data is going to be available in the queue when using memcached. Data may be evicted any time.